# Why does this graph of $\frac{\pi^{2n-1}}{\zeta(2n-1)}$ look like this past $x=16$?

Tags: riemann-zeta, math-software

As my post history will tell you, I am not particularly good at doing things practically miles above my level.  Having said that, I'm using Desmos to look at values of $\frac{\pi^{2n-1}}{\zeta(2n-1)}$ (using the closest thing to the Reimann-Zeta function I can get in Desmos) to see if it produced integral results similarly to $\zeta(2n)$.  Then [this happened:](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pki5roeswl)

[image: Graph appears to be 0 past x=16]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the calculator uses IEEE-double precision. 
As noted by @arnaud-mortier you plot the fractional part of $\frac{\pi^k}{\zeta(k)}.$

If you compute powers of $\pi$ the exponent of the double precision number $\pi^k$ increases and the available bits for the fractional part is decreasing. Here is the table for $\pi^k$

```
   k                    Pi^k           frac
   1     3.14159265358979328E+00   0.14159
   2     9.86960440108935808E+00   0.86960
   3     3.10062766802998208E+01   0.00628
   4     9.74090910340024448E+01   0.40909
   5     3.06019684785281472E+02   0.01968
   6     9.61389193575304576E+02   0.38919
   7     3.02029322777679232E+03   0.29323
   8     9.48853101607057408E+03   0.53102
   9     2.98090993334462144E+04   0.09933
  10     9.36480474760830208E+04   0.04748
  ...
  25     2.68377941431776448E+12   0.76465
  26     8.43134169187620736E+12   0.20703
  27     2.64878411191036288E+13   0.62891
  28     8.32140070692296192E+13   0.60938
  29     2.61424513284460864E+14   0.87500
  30     8.21289330402749568E+14   0.62500
  31     2.58015652686495840E+15   0.50000
  32     8.10580078991070976E+15   0.00000
  33     2.54651242130458272E+16   0.00000
  34     8.00010471504563328E+16   0.00000
  35     2.51330702007364288E+17   0.00000
```

$$\frac{\pi^{31}}{2^{52}} \approx 0.5729 \quad \frac{\pi^{32}}{2^{52}} \approx    1.7998$$
and a table for $\frac{\pi^k}{\zeta(k)}$

```
   k               Pi^k/zeta(k)      frac
   2     6.00000000000000000E+00   0.00000
   3     2.57943501666186847E+01   0.79435
   4     9.00000000000000142E+01   0.00000
   5     2.95121509929078798E+02   0.12151
   6     9.45000000000000000E+02   0.00000
   7     2.99528476444062926E+03   0.28476
   8     9.45000000000000000E+03   0.00000
   9     2.97493509504167960E+04   0.35095
  10     9.35550000000000146E+04   0.00000
  ...
  25     2.68377933433173779E+12   0.73779
  26     8.43134156623610840E+12   0.10840
  27     2.64878409217503594E+13   0.35938
  28     8.32140067592296406E+13   0.64063
  29     2.61424512797515938E+14   0.93750
  30     8.21289329637860375E+14   0.37500
  31     2.58015652566347550E+15   0.50000
  32     8.10580078802342800E+15   0.00000
  33     2.54651242100812920E+16   0.00000
```

The table are nearly identical for larger $k$ because $\zeta(k)$ rapidly converges to $1$.

To summarize: all IEEE double precision numbers $> 2^{52}$ are rounded to integers and have no fractional part.

Comment: I can tell that the fractional part gets closer to a denominator of 2, which would support it being a form of binary representation.  I think this is a sign of binary representation.  I've sent an email to Desmos's info line to confirm the specific type.

Comment: There must be some additional inaccurary from your approximation or from the calculator.
$\pi^k/\zeta(k)$ is an integer (e.g. fractional part zero) for
$k=2,4,6,8,10$ and my routines show this feature. But I cannot see any zero fractional
parts for small $k$ in your graphic.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks at the *fractional part* of $\frac{\pi^{2n-1}}{\zeta(2n-1)}$.

My bet is that at some point when $n$ becomes large, the number is so large that the computer simply neglects the fractional part.

---

Edit: when $n$ is large, the denominator is *very* close to $1$, and the numerator increases exponentially. If you ask Desmos the fractional part of $\pi^N$, you get non-zero answers until $N=2\times 16-1$ where the number is so large that Desmos apparently forgets about the fractional part. There may be a trick to force him remember it.

Comment: Okay, I'm even more confused now.  I made [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fabom4h2kc) to test this theory, and even setting the largest value in the summation to $n=1$ _still_ seems to return 0 past $x=16$.  I _literally tried one calculation_ and it's still doing it.

Comment: @weatherman115 The reason the number is large is not because of your $600$, it is because of the huge power of $\pi$!

Comment: What do you mean by that?  $\pi^{16}$ isn't that large, and is well under the limit of ~$10^{308.233}$ for Desmos.

Comment: @weatherman115 It is $\pi^{31}$. Still well under $10^{1000}$ though.

Comment: @weatherman115 Ask Desmos what $a$ is if $q=\pi^{30}$, then if $q=\pi^{31}$. You see $0.75$ then $0$. Yet $\pi^{31}$ is clearly not an integer.

Comment: But $\zeta(q)$ is still non-zero at both points.  Is there something there that's causing a problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78353/discussion-between-weatherman115-and-arnaud-mortier).

Comment: @weatherman115 I edited to make it more clear.